# Работа в php с psd

Tags: php, psd

Добрый вечер товарищи! Подскажите пожалуйста класс для **PHP**, с помощью которого можно открыть **PSD** файл, заменить в нём 4 строки(найти и заменить) и сохранить изменения в новом файле.

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов Что вы имеете ввиду под строками, exif-данные?

Comment: Даже не знаю как это описать, но если взять инструмент текст и написать что нибудь, то надо заменить этот текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть читалка PSD для PHP. Ну.... в общем... есть и то хорошо.

Насчет замены... Если речь идет о текстовом поле, можно попробовать - аккуратно не нарушая длину заменить данные в XML-структурах.

Стоит также глянуть [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15905/Yet-Another-PSD-Parser) и [тут](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/588226).

Но думаю готового решения вы не найдете. И честно говоря я с трудом представляю задача, которая бы стоила такого напряга для своего решения. Посмотрите в сторону Операций и режима пакетной обработки в самом Photoshop.

Comment: +1 за скрипт для Photoshop. Пишется на JavaScript, [подробная документация](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

Answer (score 2):

Вы пробовали использовать библиотеку **Imagemagick**?
Вроде послойно в цикле разбирает, записывая при этом каждый слой в отдельно взятый файл в заданном формате, к примеру png.

[Converting PSD with PHP/ImageMagick](http://rajeshanbiah.blogspot.ru/2009/01/converting-psd-with-phpimagemagick.html)

[Get the position (x, y) of the layer of PSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801095/php-get-the-position-x-y-of-the-layer-of-psd-file)